# How do I change iterative quicksort with fixed pivot to iterative quicksort with random pivot?

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

I found this code for quicksort with a fixed pivot. It always takes a right-hand side element of the given table as a pivot. I want it to take a random element as a pivot. I think that `x` is a pivot here, so I thought it was a good idea to change it to a random element from a given list, but it turns out that it is not working.

```
void swap ( int* a, int* b )
{
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}


int partition (int arr[], int l, int h)
{
    int x = arr[h];
    int i = (l - 1);
    for (int j = l; j <= h- 1; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] <= x)
        {
            i++;
            swap (&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap (&arr[i + 1], &arr[h]);
    return (i + 1);
}

void quickSortIterative (int arr[], int l, int h)
{
    int stack[ h - l + 1 ]; 
    int top = -1;

    stack[ ++top ] = l;
    stack[ ++top ] = h;

    while ( top >= 0 )
    {
        h = stack[ top-- ];
        l = stack[ top-- ];

        int p = partition( arr, l, h );

        if ( p-1 > l )
        {
            stack[ ++top ] = l;
            stack[ ++top ] = p - 1;
        } 
        if ( p+1 < h )
        {
            stack[ ++top ] = p + 1;
            stack[ ++top ] = h;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing lines

```
int x = arr[h];
```

and

```
swap(&arr[i+1], &arr[j]);
```

to

```
int r = l+rand()%(h-l);
int x = arr[r];
```

and then

```
swap(&arr[i+1], &arr[r]);
```

but it is not sorting properly. Obviously I'm doing something wrong here. Please help.

Comment: Any reason why recursion is replaced with the use of variable-length arrays? It's not going to save you from stack overflows.

Comment: @Alexey Frunze It is my college exercise. I am supposed to compare different kinds of quicksorts. No problems with recursive one (either with fixed and random pivot), but iterative was a problem to implement for me. I ended up using someone else's code and that resulted in not understanding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your partition function assumes the pivot is at the end of the partition.
Consider moving your random pivot to the end of the partition first.

i.e. add

```
swap(&arr[r], &arr[h]);
```

after choosing your pivot.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the 'partition' function now moves the pivot so it doesn't remain at the `r` index. And the function also misses the last element (at index `h`).
The simplest solution would be to place the pivot to the right-most position just after selecting it, and remain everything other the same: put `swap(&arr[r], &arr[h]);` before the first loop in `partition()`, and restore the last swap to `swap (&arr[i + 1], &arr[h]);`